# How to stay on the same panel after submitting form using PHP when using one form with multiple panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a step-wizard form with multiple panels within it, I would like to stay on the same panel after I submit using php. Lets say I am on step 2 and submit, I want it to stay on step2(panel 2)
I have tried but when I submit the page loads and it takes me back to step 1(panel 1) instead of staying on step 2(panel 2). How can I solve this?

Bellow is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">


        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-wizard">
                <li class="active"><a href="#step-1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="nmbr">1</span>Verification</a></li>
                <li><a href="#step-2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><span class="nmbr">2</span>Form</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form action="stack.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


                <div class="panel panel-borderless setup-content" id="step-1" style="margin-top:8px">


                    <label style="font-weight:normal">Code:</label>
                    <input type="string" name="code" />
                    <label style="font-weight:normal">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" />

                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button" name="next1" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>

                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-borderless setup-content" id="step-2" style="margin-top:8px">


                    <label style="font-weight:normal">item Code:</label>
                    <input type="string" name="itemcode" />
                    <label style="font-weight:normal">item Name:</label>
                    <input type="string" name="itemname" />


                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="submit" name="add">add</button> 
                </div>

            </form>


            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var navListItems = $('.nav-wizard li a'),
                            allWells = $('.setup-content'),
                            allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');
                    dis = $('#step-1');

                    allWells.hide();
                    dis.show();

                    navListItems.click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                                $item = $(this);

                        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
                            navListItems.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
                            $item.addClass('btn-success');
                            allWells.hide();
                            $target.show();
                            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
                        }
                    });

                    allNextBtn.click(function () {
                        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
                                curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
                                nextStepWizard = $('.nav-wizard li a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
                                curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
                                isValid = true;

                        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                        for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
                            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
                                isValid = false;
                                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                            }
                        }

                        if (isValid)
                            nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
                    });

                    $('.nav-wizard li a.btn-success').trigger('click');
                });

            </script> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: don't submit the form, serialize it and save it with ajax (javascript).

Comment: either use ajax (to avoid a postback), or in your form put a hidden field which contains the ID of the panel you're on currently (you'd probably have to keep it up to date with some javascript). The PHP can then read that value when the form is posted back (from the POST variables) and use it to ensure that panel is displayed first when re-creating the page.

Comment: how do i do that?im new to ajax

Comment: how to make an ajax request? If you're completely new to it I suggest you find a tutorial and some examples first, otherwise you won't really understand anything we tell you to do. Since you're using jquery, I'd suggest using their $.ajax() method (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make the request, it's neater and easier to use than the native JS syntax.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Let me see how ajax works, if I fail I will try to use PHP as you said above. Thank you so much